# How can I tell if a Chrome app is already running

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm looking for means of telling whether other instances of a Chrome app are already running but Chrome's excellent context isolation makes it quite difficult.

Also, I was hoping chrome.runtime APIs would help but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Essentially, I want to make sure only one instance can run at any given time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your background page can store global state that lets you keep track of which windows have been launched by the app.

Your app can only have one background (or event) page at a time.

If you are wanting to prevent multiple windows from launching, make sure your chrome.app.window.create call has an "id" option. That means only one window will be created with that given id.